# eclipse : Filtering for System.out.print calls

Tags: eclipse

I want to have a check in place so that any print commands donot get checked into svn when i checkin my code.
I installed "Checkstyle " plugin on eclipse but problem is that it gives error even if print command has been commented out.

My requirement is to ignore print commands in comments but not in main code.

Any info in this regard will be of gr8 help.

Regards
Lokesh

Comment: What are the errors in both cases?

Comment: Sorry i was not clear there. I have set severity level to error for this check in my checkstyle settings, so even if a System.out.println command is commented out, checkstyle still gives it as project error.

Comment: So it is the same error if you comment it out? Whats the name of the rule you use?

Comment: Yes, it gives same error. I have created my own custom rule in which i check for regular expression "System\.out\.println".

Comment: Ah, now we are getting there. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Andre has the right answer, but you might also consider using log4j to capture logging, trace and debug information.  By changing the properties file you can filter out anything but error or fatal messages.  Having said that, that's a fairly big refactoring and Andre's got the right answer to your question.

Comment: @Chris has a point. The clean way to make outputs is a logger and log4j is kind of a best practice. But if I got you right you want to make sure that the prints don't make it into productive code. I think it's OK to use them locally for debug if they are removed as soon as the error is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using "Regex" option under "Miscellaneous" [Preferences -> checkstyle->Miscellaneous->Regex] as it has option to ignore comments.

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2):

As you told me in the comments, you used a custom rule using the regular expression `"System\.out\.println"`. This seems to match every line that contains that string even if there are comments before it. You have to change your regex to match only lines that doesn't contain `//` before the command. `"(?!//).*System\.out\.println"` should work.

**EDIT**

Just remembered that PMD has an integrated rule for using `System.out.println()`. You could use that as an alternative to a custom checkstyle rule. Sadly the Eclipse plugin is not available for Juno yet but if you use an earlier version you should be fine.

Comment: I agree with your approach but checkstyle still gives commented lines as error. Probably its not able to recognise negation expression.

Answer (score 2):

I have filtered calls to 'System.out' and 'System.err'using [RegexpSingleLineJava](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSinglelineJava) check with `^System\.(out|err)\.print(ln|f){0,1}\(.*\)` as regex parameter

Comment: IMHO the correct answer as `RegexpSingleLineJava`  has the option `ignoreComments`